# How to kill port forwarding once you have have finished using it

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, unison

In order to sync my home and work file systems I need to go via an intermediary computer and use port forwarding. Let us call the home computer A, the intermediate one B and the work computer C. From the command line I do this

```
ssh -N -f -L 2025:C:22 me_B@B && unison foo ssh://me_C@localhost:2025/foo
```

- I would like to put this one-liner into a bash script. How can I make it quit gracefully at the end and not leave any port forwarding still set up?

Comment: Why the down vote? It is a programming question.

Comment: It should just work automatically, if you put that into a script.

Comment: @JohnZwinck It leaves behind "ssh -N -f -L 2025:C:22 me_B@B"  which I can see by doing `ps auwx|grep ssh`.

Comment: Hmm, that surprises me.  You can try using `trap EXIT` in Bash to run a function when the master script exits, and in that function you can kill the PID of `ssh` (which you can get by `$!` if you start it in the background initially).

Comment: @JohnZwinck This sounds good but I may need more hand holding than that I am afraid. If you get a chance to add an answer that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -N -f -L 2025:C:22 me_B@B &
pid=$! # ssh PID
rc=$? # ssh return code

# set up to kill ssh when this script finishes
function finish {
  kill $pid
}
trap finish EXIT

[ $rc -eq 0 ] && unison foo ssh://me_C@localhost:2025/foo
```

Comment: Thanks. This almost works perfectly (I have to remove the & so I can enter the ssh passwords). I think as a result of this I get "Looking for changes
  Waiting for changes from server
Reconciling changes
Nothing to do: replicas have not changed since last sync.
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
"  Not putting it in the background mucks things up it seems but I have to do be able to enter the passwords.

Comment: If `kill` is printing its usage, then `$pid` is not right somehow.  Maybe try `export pid=$!` after launching ssh?  I'm not too sure right now.