# How to close ssh connections opened via script

Tags: bash, ssh

I use the following script to open a ssh tunnel to a bunch servers always varying between mysql, redis and ssh ports.
I am doing this while being in the company vpn, but I had the same problem back in the days, when you worked in the office.

Usually I start the script and use the opened connection with other tools like SequelPro or PhpStorm to connect to webserver or databases. Ideally it would just run until I don't need it any more and then I would  exit the jumpserver and the connections should close. That is fine as long as I don't loose the connection and get kicked out of the jumpserver.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

username="my-user"
jumpServer="my.bastionserver.net"
hosts=("my.awsserver1.com" "my.awsserver2.com" "my.awsserver3.com")

destMysqlPort=3306
destSshPort=22
destRedisPort=6379

x=10001
y=10002
z=10003

for i in "${hosts[@]}"; do
  :
  server=$i
  sshTunnel="$sshTunnel -L $x:$server:$destMysqlPort -L $y:$server:$destSshPort -L $y:$server:$destRedisPort"
  echo "Server: $server -- MYSQL: $x -- SSH: $y-- Redis: $z"
  x=$((x + 3))
  y=$((y + 3))
  z=$((z + 3))
done

if [ -z "$sshTunnel" ]
then
  echo "ssh tunnels are empty"
else
  ssh $sshTunnel $username@$jumpServer -i ~/.ssh/aws
fi
```

the output is as follows:

```sh
$ ./awstunnel.sh
Server: my.awsserver1.com -- MYSQL: 10001 -- SSH: 10002-- Redis: 10003
Server: my.awsserver1.com -- MYSQL: 10004 -- SSH: 10005-- Redis: 10006
Server: my.awsserver1.com -- MYSQL: 10007 -- SSH: 10008-- Redis: 10009
[...]
```

When I try to connect again via this script  I get the messages that the address is already in use:

```sh
bind [127.0.0.1]:10002: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 10002
bind [127.0.0.1]:10005: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 10005
[...]
```

**How can I change the script so that I can start it again right away and don't have to wait for quite some time until the connection via this tunnel really closes?**

I work from a Mac and the jumpserver is a Linux server, where I should not change settings.

Comment: Sounds like you are actually looking for a way to reconnect to a connection when you were disconnected. Look for `tmux` or `screen`

Comment: Reconnect or actively close the open connections before opening others, both would be fine.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not really a programming question then, but if you have `tmux` installed on the jump host, it should be like five minutes to replace your current configuration, and maybe 20 to refactor your existing script to use `tmux` to set up the connections from scratch again in the future (though the need for that should be significantly less frequent then).

Comment: In very brief, `ssh -t jumphost tmux attach -t foo` to reattach to an existing session named `foo` if you lose your connection to it.

Comment: Regrettably tmux doesn't exist there and I should not install software on it, since it isn't "my" jumpserver.

Comment: Could I add a loop at the beginning of my script, where all maybe open connections are force closed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505294/how-to-kill-port-forwarding-once-you-have-have-finished-using-it

Comment: The answer to that one also looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447226/how-to-close-this-ssh-tunnel

Comment: If you aren't familiar with `ControlMaster`/`ControlSocket` functionality in ssh, they may be worth looking into -- openssh is perfectly capable of managing background processes for jump hosts completely on its own with no explicit scripts needing to be written for the purpose in the first place.

Comment: ...play your cards right, and you can avoid needing a tunnel at all, instead having a ControlMaster-managed transport and spawning a new openssh client that opens a channel on that transport whenever you want a new connection through said already-open transport.

Answer (score 1):

Just like this, a little hint:

To get the PID of the last executed command you have to type:

```
echo "$!"
```

So, what you can do is just store the PID after each ssh login command like this for example:

```
#Store the pid of the last command in a variable named sshPid: 
sshPid=$!
```

and when you are done just kill the corresponding PID with:

```
kill ${sshPid}
```

Tell me if that worked for you :p

Bguess

Comment: The problem happens not "when I am done" In that case I exit the jumpserver connection I opened via the script and all my ssh connections are closed too. 
The problem happens, when I loose the connection and my shell window freezes and I cannot do anything beside closing the shell window and open a new one. Then my ssh connections still block the ports.

Comment: Look at answer 1 here from the link above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505294/how-to-kill-port-forwarding-once-you-have-have-finished-using-it